# LeftArrow on my html and js project not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

Yesterday I started working on a game using JavaScript for the first time.
I've been trying to do a game (Right now its only suposed to be 2 rectangles that can move) the problem is that when i press the left Arrow the red revtangle is not moving to the left but it is to right.

```
const player = new Sprite({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 }, velocity: { x: 0, y: 0 }})

const enemy = new Sprite({ position: { x: 400, y: 100 }, velocity: { x: 0, y: 0 }});

const keys = {
    a: { pressed: false },
    d: { pressed: false },
    w: { pressed: false },
    ArrowRight: { pressed: false },
    ArrowLeft: { pressed: false }
}

let lastKey

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.fillStyle = "black"
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    player.update()
    enemy.update()

    player.velocity.x = 0
    enemy.velocity.x = 0

    // movimiento del player1
    if (keys.a.pressed && lastKey === "a") {
        player.velocity.x = -1
    } else if (keys.d.pressed && lastKey === "d") {
        player.velocity.x = 1
    }

    // movimiento del player2
    if (keys.ArrowLeft.pressed && enemy.lastKey === "ArrowLeft") {
        enemy.velocity.x = -1
    } else if (keys.ArrowRight.pressed && enemy.lastKey === "ArrowRight") {
        enemy.velocity.x = 1
    }
}

animate()

window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    console.log(event.key)
    switch (event.key) {
     case "d":
        keys.d.pressed = true
        lastKey = "d"
        break   
     case "a":
        keys.a.pressed = true
        lastKey = "a"
        break
     case "w":
        player.velocity.y = -10
        break


     case "ArrowRight":
        keys.ArrowRight.pressed = true
        enemy.lastKey = "ArrowRight"
        break   
     case "ArroyLeft":
        keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = true
        enemy.lastKey = "ArrowLeft"
        break
     case "ArrowUp":
        enemy.velocity.y = -10
        break
    }
    console.log(event.key);
})

window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
     case "d":
        keys.d.pressed = false
        break
     case "a":
        keys.a.pressed = false
        break
    }

    //Input de los enemigos
    switch (event.key) {
     case "ArrowRight":
        keys.ArrowRight.pressed = false
        break
     case "ArrowLeft":
        keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = false
        break
    }
    console.log(event.key);
})
```

The red rectangle is not moving (Only on the let site the right site is working well.)
I'd apreciate any help.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. Please include the missing code for the Sprite class.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ssnXfQxP That's all the code I have.